# Android SQLite sync updates from server

Tags: java, android

I just wanted some advice. I have an app with a database that will be updated once a week. In my opinion there is no point having users download the app again each week. Nor is there a reason for the entire database to be downloaded once a week.

My idea is to send a request to a server every time the app is opened with the version of the database. The server compares this version to the current and if it is out of sync the rows will be returned via something like a json reply.

If there are better methods for this or if there are valid reasons why the options I have discounted are much better, please do tell me.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I tweaked the title (and fixed a typo)

Comment: cheers. Always nice when someone states what they have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a SQLite DB on the server and just ship it down, pre-made basically. Otherwise, your flow sounds about right.